# LDAP Authentication With Liferay 7.0 GA3

Tags: liferay-7

I'm new into Liferay 7. I was investigating how to Login into the Liferay Portal using an external Database, in my case I'd like users to auth into my portal using an external LDAP DB.

I've investigated stuff and haven't found too much about it. Specially since most of the doc and samples I've found are on Liferay 6.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official LDAP integration documentation : https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/ldap

Answer (score 0):

From the link provided <s>above</s>, by Esteban, i gather it is similar to 6.2 (and I know that one).

Ldap for liferay is configured partly in the portal web environment (control-> controlpanel -> configuration -> authentication, in 6.2 at least) and partly in the settings files on the server.

It syncs well with both openldap and any AD, and even with combinations of both.
It imports users from a specified OU, and syncs groups such that you can automatically organize who sees which site/content.

Does this answer your question?